# How to use airbnb epoxy in Android project?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, epoxy

I am trying to integrate and use epoxy in my project, I have copied modules epoxy-adapter, epoxy-annotations, epoxy-databinding, epoxy-litho, epoxy-processor into my project, but the classes with _ that are supposed to be generated at the build are not getting generated. 
PS:- I dont have any code to paste here. I have done enough research and could not get result.

Comment: Have you check epoxy: https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy#min-sdk